# What is the difference between troops and soldiers?

Tags: vocabulary

I've seen conflicting information in several places and I'm really confused.
Are troops a subset of the group soldiers?  Or is troops simply a number of soldiers with a common goal?

Comment: There's more difference when they're singular than plural.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Cambridge definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/troops).

Soldiers are the individual people. A troop is a unit of cavalry, but 'troops' in the plural refers to a large number of service personnel when they are sent on a particular task.

Comment: Also a troop is not necessarily a group of service personnel, especially as an accepted alternative spelling of troupe, meaning a group of performers.

Comment: @timchessish - I was assuming that the question was asked in the military context.

Comment: Kate's is the only decent answer so far. The others may safely be disregarded.

Comment: @Kate, I got that, I thought extra info might be useful. It's the only real distinction between troops and soldiers.

Comment: @timchessish - a troop is not a troupe, in the way a coop is not a coupe.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - and a loop is not a loupe. I don't think there is such a thing as a 'snoupe', but let me tell you, if there was, a snoop wouldn't be one!

Comment: Troops can also be used more generically as a term for military personnel in general. "Support the troops!" "Bring the troops back home."

Comment: @DoneWithThis According to Chambers "troop" IS an alternative spelling for "troupe".

Comment: @timchessish - we can use 'troop' for a group of people or animals that move or operate together, such as a troop of monkeys or a troop of actors. We can also use 'troupe' for these, but not for military situations. Except maybe a World War 2 ENSA party, but I don't expect you to understand that.

Comment: @Michael Harvey - as I said,  a troop of actors uses troop as an alternative spelling of troupe. I'm not old enough to remember WW2 ENSA but remember Spike and the others who came through it. Not sure why I wouldn't understand that?

Comment: @timchessish - sorry, I didn't think you were old enough!

Comment: @timchessish - please quote your source for 'troop' being an acceptable spelling for a group of actors.

Comment: @Michael Harvey - Chambers, "8. A troupe"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey not quite old enough for the Goons but saw Spike live.